# Flex box shrink spacers when space is constrained

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I shrink spacers within a flex layout when space is constrained, but allow them to grow up to a `max-height` when space is available?

In this example, green spacers should each take up vertical space between the items in the yellow `<article>` element, until they reach the `max-height`, or there is no more space available and the `<article>` is the same height as the `<aside>`.

If there are a more items added to the `<article>` and there is no more vertical space spare, the spacers should shrink as necessary until they are `0px` tall rather than cause the `<article>` to become taller than the `<aside>`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  background: #FFDCFF;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

article {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #FFFFDC;
}

article .spacer {
  flex-grow: 999;
  flex-shrink: 999;
  max-height: 20px;
  background: green;
}

aside {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #DCFFFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article class="article">
    <div>item</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div>item</div>
  </article>
  <aside>
    some content<br />
    that takes up<br />
    a lot of<br />
    vertical space<br />
    on the right<br />
  </aside>
</body>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. I think the problem is that you want to control the height of the elements, but you cannot do that with the `flexbox`, I advise you to use the `grid layout` to control the height of the elements.

I've added some elements and reset styles to your code, and commented your old styles for comparison.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: unset;
  background: #FFDCFF;
}

main {
  /* display: flex;
  background: #FFDCFF;
  align-items: flex-start; */

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items: start;
}

article {
  /* flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #FFFFDC; */

  background: #FFFFDC;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article .spacer {
  /* flex-grow: 999;
  flex-shrink: 999;
  max-height: 20px;
  background: green; */

  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

aside {
  /* flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #DCFFFF; */

  background: #DCFFFF;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <main>
    <article class="article">
      <div>item</div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div>item</div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div>item</div>
    </article>
    <aside>
      some content<br />
      that takes up<br />
      a lot of<br />
      vertical space<br />
      on the right<br />
      on the right<br />
    </aside>
    </main>
  </body>
```